# Change dropdown menu color in default Maverick theme?

Tags: 10.10, themes, appearance

Does anybody know if and how I might be able to change the color of the dropdown menus in Maverick's default theme?

I like most parts of the theme enough to not really want to change, but I find the black dropdown menus hard to stomach.

I think the inverse would be nice and would provide a nice contrast with the black menu and title bars.

However, the customize dialog (in Appearance) doesn't give the option to make this change. Is there another way?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to have a look at the [Gtk theming tutorial](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeArt/Tutorials/GtkThemes).

Comment: This page does not exist yet. You can create a new empty page, or use one of the page templates.

Answer (score 0):

That's a bit difficult, you have to modify `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc` file. It's not as difficult as it seems to be, the syntax is very intuitive. I don't know how is the dropmenu called in this progamming language, but it must be something with «menu», I think. The only thing you have to know is RGB code of colors.

I had a look at the file and it seems to be the  `style "menu" = "dark" {`  part in gtkrc.

Remember to make a backup.